# Can a conditional statement be used to express "exactly one"?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

My question is regarding Example 2.2.2. of Velleman's 'How to Prove It' ([pg. 71](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=v_NIEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA71&ots=Nej0kizF4s&dq=%22John%20likes%20exactly%20one%20person.%22%20google%20books&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q=%22John%20likes%20exactly%20one%20person.%22%20google%20books&f=false)). We are asked to write the statement "John likes exactly one person" in terms of quantifiers (note, $\exists!$ has not been introduced yet).

**My attempt:**

I started by breaking the statement down as follows:

"There exists a person $x$ that John likes and John does not like all other persons $y$ who are not $x$."

and then:

"There exists a person $x$ that John likes and for all persons $y$, if $y \neq x$, then John does not like them."

and then expressed this using quantifiers:

$$∃x[L(j, x) ∧ ∀y[(y ≠ x) → ￢L(j, y)]]$$

where $L(j, m)$ is the statement "John likes m."

**Questions**

- Is it correct to use an implication here?

I know that in order for my answer to be correct, the statement $(y ≠ x) → ￢L(j, y)$ must be true **for all** $y$. But I'm not sure if it is in this case, since John likes *exactly one* person, so it it is not possible for ￢L(j, y) to be true if (y ≠ x) is false.

- Would a biconditional be better? i.e. $∃x[L(j, x) ∧ ∀y[(y ≠ x) ↔ ￢L(j, y)]]$.

---

The solution given by the author is $∃x(L( j, x)∧¬∃y(L( j, y) ∧ y \neq x))$. I tried checking if my solution was equivalent, as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
¬∃y[L(j, y) ∧ y ≠ x] 
\\& = ∀y¬[L(j, y) ∧ y ≠ x]  &&\text{(quantifier negation)} 
\\& = ∀y[¬L(j, y) ∨ ¬y ≠ x]  &&\text{(DeMorgan)} 
\\& = ∀y[¬L(j, y) ∨ y = x]  &&\text{(double negation)}
\\& = ∀y[L(j, y) → y = x]  &&\text{(conditional)}
\\& = ∀y[y ≠ x → ¬L(j, y)]  &&\text{(contrapositive)}
\end{align*}$$

So it seems my solution is equivalent, but I'm still not sure why it's ok to use an implication to express "exactly one".

Comment: The "theory" to manage it is to parse "there is exactly one Philosopher" as : "there is one Phil and everything that is a Phil is identical with the previous one". In symbols $\exists !xPx$ is $\exists x (Px \land \forall y (Py \to y=x))$

Comment: Thus, you first formula is correct.

Comment: And yes, your verification about the equivalence of the formula with the author's one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a biconditional, then, translating back into English, you statement would mean:

There exists a person $x$ that John likes and for all persons $y$, if $y \ne x$, then John does not like $y$, *and* if $y = x$ then John does like $y$.

Now, to say "for all persons $y$, if $y = x$ then John does like $y$" is just a roundabout way of saying "John likes $x$."  So by changing the conditional to a biconditional, you are, in effect, adding "and John likes $x$" to your statement.  But you've already said that.  So using a biconditional isn't wrong, but it's redundant.